# Cannot find PID file after reinstall of mysql

Tags: mysql, database, homebrew

I was getting an error that server quit without updating pid file. So I thought I would uninstall it and install it again.

I had installed it with homebrew last time so I did:

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

and to install it I did:

```
brew install mysql
```

Even after this however, I am still getting the same error.

```
$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Tirths-MBP.fios-router.home.pid).
```

Comment: Anything else in the error logs?

Comment: Check that the account mysql is running under has access to the directory that the pid file is being stored in

Comment: how can i check that? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Dont know, my Unix is very rusty and unused

Answer (score 0):

If this mysql like a linux binaries; Try to regen PID with mysqld_safe as :

stop server

```
bin>$./mysql.server stop
```

regen PID file :

```
bin>$./mysqld_safe -u youruser&
```

then try to start mysql as :

```
bin>$./mysql.server start
```

p.s.
...and do you have `etc/my.cnf` file gen-ed ? It would be more helpful you to provide logs;

---

Hope this helps; Report your results please;

Comment: I did what you said to no avail, and yes I do have the etc/my.cnf generated. How do I provide logs? Sorry very beginner here. If it helps I dont have any information in databases right now so i could do a complete wipe of mysql somehow and reinstall it that would be fine.

Comment: @TirthAllsparkRami You run the script from within the mysql bin folder? To test don't use sys vars please; Did you modify mysql conf files? What about conf files what is the content in etc/my.cnf and mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf ?